# React.unmountComponentAtNode | 15.4.1 | Object doesn't support property or method 'unmountComponentAtNode'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am importing with the below statement

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
```

and I want to use `unmountComponentAtNode` but keeps getting the error

> Object doesn't support property or method 'unmountComponentAtNode'
>
> React.unmountComponentAtNode(document.getElementById('root'));

I'm using an old version of the React library (15.4.1).

So how should I call `unmountComponentAtNode` so that I do not get an error:

> unmountComponentAtNode is not exported by 'react'?

What should I import so that I do not get an error?

Comment: Isn't it part of ReactDOM and not React?

Answer (score 1):

The [big change](https://reactjs.org/blog/2016/11/16/react-v15.4.0.html) in v15.4 was the separation of React and ReactDOM. unmountComponentAtNode() became a method of ReactDOM. Use:

```
ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(document.getElementById('root'));
```